# Configuring Dedicated Memcached caching from Java in Azure

Tags: java, eclipse, azure

I have followed the [instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj870767.aspx) for settings Memcached on azure from Java...

My question is what do I put as my entry point in my csdef file for the dedicated caching worker role?

Currently it works locally with the "default" run.cmd which simply monitors that the java process is up. This is not going to work when running on azure because the java process won't be there (it is getting this java process from the application worker role - the role actually running the application).

Answer (score 0):

you might need to upload your own JRE to your WorkerRole and start Java from ProgramEntryPoint.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up working out the name of the exe that *calls* the entry point and I made that the executable that is monitored by the run.cmd. So the run.cmd monitors that executable that called it. It's crude, but it worked.